# Scala multi dimensional data structures

Tags: scala, multidimensional-array

i am new in Scala and i would like to ask what is the MOST EFFICIENT way to implement this problem.

Imagine that we have a stadium, which has X sectors and each sector has Y rows and each row has Z seats.

Imagine that we have random number of occupied seats.

a) Given a row, return the amount of occupied seats.

b) Given a sector, return the amount of occupied seats.

c) Given a sector and a row, make sure the chair is vacant x (1 <= x <= n).

d) Given a row, returns an array with the positions of the vacant chairs.

e) Given a sector, return the row with the greatest amount of vacant chairs.

f) Return the amount of occupied stadium chairs.

g) Suppose the entrance to the stadium has two values: $ 75.00 for the two closest rows to the field and $ 50.00 for the other rows . Write a function that returns the income of a game.

Thank for your solutions in advance

Comment: Tempted to close this as too broad; it sounds like you want other people to submit your homework

Comment: no its not a homework, its just an exercise that i want to do, and i am thinking of a way how to do it most efficiently

Comment: Exercise from where? It's clear you didn't write it.

Answer (score 0):

Most efficiently can mean in terms of your effort writing the code or in terms of runtime speed. In the former case, I would use something like a nested `Vector`. In the latter case, probably a flat `Array` would perform best.

```
val rows = 4
val cols = 3
val arr  = new Array[Boolean](rows * cols)

def get(row: Int, col: Int)                 = arr(row * cols + col)
def set(row: Int, col: Int, value: Boolean) = arr(row * cols + col) = value

def occupiedInRow(row: Int) = (0 until cols).count(get(row, _))

set(row = 1, col = 0, value = true)
set(row = 1, col = 2, value = true)
assert(occupiedInRow(1) == 2)
```

Accordingly for three or more dimensions.

Unless this is for your exercise, I would use an existing optimised library such as [Breeze or Saddle](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/pubs/slides/thoughtworks_scientific_2014/slides.html).

Comment: thank you for your fast reply really appreciate it, most efficient in the term of computation speed. I am sorry cos i am new in scala, so what you are saying the best thing to do is to generate an array 4*3, meaning cols represents sectors, rows represents rows of seats, right? but how can i set the number of seats in each row ?  Thanks again

Comment: Beware as I haven't tested the performance, sometimes it is surprising which is actually better. But a flat array means the JVM will only perform an index-out-of-bounds checks once instead of N times where N is the number of dimensions. In general `Array` have the fastest access and update times, but being mutable can be problem for reasoning, and the size can't grow without copying the array. Also arrays are specialised for primitive types which is currently not the case for Scala collections which thus have overhead from boxing/unboxing (e.g. `Boolean` in this case)

Comment: If the number of seats in each row is not the same, you cannot use a regular grid / flat array. Then you must use nested arrays or vectors that allow different sizes for each row.

Comment: the number of seats in each rows are the same, for example we have 4 sectors each sectors has 10 rows, and each raw has 20 seats which can be occupied or unoccupied

Answer (score 0):

I think that most efficient way to map `Boolean`s is [`BitSet`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.BitSet) it comes in two flavors: [mutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.BitSet) and [immutable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.BitSet). Immutable are little bit more efficient, but it's efficiency is disappearing in any concurrent\distributed situation.
Here is the implementation <s>of your homework</s>:

```
object Stadium {
  def random(sectors: Int, rows: Int, seats: Int): Stadium = {
    val size = sectors * rows * seats
    new Stadium(sectors, rows, seats,
      BitSet fromBitMask Array.fill(size / 64 + 1)(Random.nextLong()) take size)
  }

  def apply(occupied: (Int, Int, Int)*): Stadium = {
    val sectors = occupied.map(_._1).max + 1
    val rows = occupied.map(_._2).max + 1
    val seats = occupied.map(_._3).max + 1
    val occNums = occupied map {
      case (sector, row, seat) => (sector * rows + row) * seats + seat
    }
    Stadium(sectors, rows, seats, BitSet(occNums: _*))
  }

  def income[N: Numeric](stadium: Stadium, standardPrice: N, premiumPrice: PartialFunction[Int, N] = PartialFunction.empty) = (
    for {
      sector <- 0 until stadium.sectors
      row <- 0 until stadium.rows
      price = premiumPrice.applyOrElse[Int, N](row, _ => standardPrice)
      occupied = implicitly[Numeric[N]].fromInt(stadium.occupiedInRow(sector, row))
    } yield price * occupied
    ).sum
}

case class Stadium(sectors: Int, rows: Int, seats: Int, occupied: BitSet) {
  @inline final def sectorSeats = rows * seats
  def rowRange(sector: Int, row: Int) = {
    val from = (sector * rows + row) * seats
    occupied.range(from, from + seats) map (_ - from)
  }
  def sectorRange(sector: Int) = {
    val from = sector * sectorSeats
    occupied.range(from, from + sectorSeats) map (_ - from)
  }
  lazy val wholeRow = BitSet(0 until seats: _*)
  def occupiedInRow(sector: Int, row: Int) = rowRange(sector, row).size
  def occupiedInSector(sector: Int) = sectorRange(sector).size
  def isOccupied(sector: Int, row: Int, seat: Int) = occupied(sector * sectorSeats + row * seats + seat)
  def isVacant(sector: Int, row: Int, seat: Int) = !isOccupied(sector, row, seat)
  def vacantInRow(sector: Int, row: Int) = wholeRow &~ rowRange(sector, row)
  def mostVacant(sector: Int) = 0 until rows maxBy (vacantInRow(sector, _).size)
  def occupiedSize = occupied.size
}
```

So. If you like to define your stadium like:

```
val st = Stadium((0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,2,2), (0,2,1))
```

Income with standard price $50 will be calculated easily

```
Stadium.income(st, 50.0) // res0: Double = 250.0
```

And could be increased for first two rows

```
Stadium.income(st, 50.0, Seq.fill(2)(75.0))// res1: Double = 325.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and again its not a homework :) ust to make sure if i got it correctly, random method takes in number of seats, rows, sectors to create and return a new stadium object with randumly occipied seats right ? Can you please explain to me what apply occupied method does ? the income method takes in two parameters : stadium and price of seats(premium/normal) depends on if its premium or regular it calculates the income right ? rowRange defines number of seats in the row right? sectorRange defines number of seats in the sector right ? what does wholeRow do ? Thank you